# Structuring a project that generates triangles inside triangles

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, graphics

Basically I made this completely useless program that generates triangles inside triangles. Its not perfect yet but my question is about the structure. I am generally happy with it but I want to know if it could have been  better. There are six files and here they are.

main.cpp

```
#define OLC_PGE_APPLICATION
//Link to pixel game engine header file
//https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/blob/master/olcPixelGameEngine.h
#include "pixelGameEngine.h"
#include "triangleProcessor.h"

class TriInsideTri : public olc::PixelGameEngine
{
public:
    TriInsideTri(int sw, int sh) :
        sw(sw), sh(sh)
    {
        sAppName = "TriInsideTri";
    }
private:
    int sw;
    int sh;
    TriangleProcessor triangleProcessor{ sw, sh };

public:
    bool OnUserCreate() override
    {
        return true;
    }
    bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime) override
    {
        World::DragToChangeOffset(this);
        World::WSToChangeScale(this);
        triangleProcessor.Run(this);
        triangleProcessor.Render(this);
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int screenWidth = 600;
    int screenHeight = 600;
    int pixelSize = 1;
    TriInsideTri tritnsidetri{ screenWidth / pixelSize, screenHeight / pixelSize };
    if (tritnsidetri.Construct(screenWidth / pixelSize, screenHeight / pixelSize, 
        pixelSize, pixelSize))
    {
        tritnsidetri.Start();
    }
}
```

Triangle.h

```
#pragma once
#include "pixelGameEngine.h"

class Triangle
{
public:
    Triangle() = default;
    Triangle(olc::vf2d p1, olc::vf2d p2, olc::vf2d p3):
        p1(p1), p2(p2), p3(p3)
    {
    }

private:
    static constexpr float oneFourth = 0.25f;
    static constexpr float half = 0.50f;
    static constexpr float threeFourth = 0.75f;

private:
    static olc::vf2d Lerp(const olc::vf2d& p1, const olc::vf2d& p2, const float alpha) noexcept
    {
        return p1 + (p2 - p1) * alpha;
    }

public:
    //Inner triangles for flat tops are generated differently
    //to flat bottoms.
    bool flatTop = false;

public:
    //First and last are not Used. Just for messing around
    //to make wierd triangles
    //static olc::vf2d First(const olc::vf2d& p1, const olc::vf2d& p2) noexcept
    //{
    //  return Lerp(p1, p2, oneFourth);
    //}

    static olc::vf2d Mid(const olc::vf2d& p1, const olc::vf2d& p2) noexcept
    {
        return Lerp(p1, p2, half);
    }

    //static olc::vf2d Last(const olc::vf2d& p2, const olc::vf2d& p1) noexcept
    //{
    //  return Lerp(p1, p2, threeFourth);
    //}

public:
    //left and right and the same for flat top and 
    //bottom. FbTop is flat bottom's top point and
    //Ftbottom is flat top's bottom point. 
    static olc::vf2d FbTop(olc::vf2d p1, olc::vf2d p2, olc::vf2d p3) noexcept
    {
        if (p1.y > p2.y) std::swap(p1, p2);
        if (p2.y > p3.y) std::swap(p2, p3);
        if (p1.y > p2.y) std::swap(p1, p2);
        return p1;
    }

    static olc::vf2d FtBottom(olc::vf2d p1, olc::vf2d p2, olc::vf2d p3) noexcept
    {
        if (p1.y < p2.y) std::swap(p1, p2);
        if (p2.y < p3.y) std::swap(p2, p3);
        if (p1.y < p2.y) std::swap(p1, p2);
        return p1;
    }

    static olc::vf2d Right(olc::vf2d p1, olc::vf2d p2, olc::vf2d p3) noexcept
    {
        if (p1.x > p2.x) std::swap(p1, p2);
        if (p2.x > p3.x) std::swap(p2, p3);
        if (p1.x > p2.x) std::swap(p1, p2);
        return p1;
    }

    static olc::vf2d Left(olc::vf2d p1, olc::vf2d p2, olc::vf2d p3) noexcept
    {
        if (p1.x < p2.x) std::swap(p1, p2);
        if (p2.x < p3.x) std::swap(p2, p3);
        if (p1.x < p2.x) std::swap(p1, p2);
        return p1;
    }

public:
    olc::vf2d p1{}, p2{}, p3{};
};
```

triangleProcessor.h

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include "pixelGameEngine.h"
#include "triangle.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include "input.h"
#include "world.h"

class TriangleProcessor
{
public:
    TriangleProcessor(const int sw, const int sh)
    {
        //Initialize the vector with the first triangle
        vvTris.push_back
        (//vvtris
            { //vtris
                { //triangle
                    {sw * 0.5f, 0.0f}, //olc::vf2d
                    {0.0f, sh * 1.0f}, //olc::vf2d
                    {sw * 1.0f, sh * 1.0f} //olc::vf2d
                }
            }
        );
    }
    TriangleProcessor(const TriangleProcessor&) = delete;
    TriangleProcessor& operator=(const TriangleProcessor&) = delete;

private:
    using vTris = std::vector<Triangle>;
    std::vector<vTris> vvTris;
    Gfx gfx{};
    Input input{};

private:
    void GenerateMiddleTriangle(const Triangle& tri, vTris& newVTris) noexcept
    {
        Triangle midTri =
        {
            Triangle::Mid(tri.p1, tri.p2),
            Triangle::Mid(tri.p2, tri.p3),
            Triangle::Mid(tri.p3, tri.p1)
        };

        midTri.flatTop = true;
        newVTris.push_back(midTri);
    }

    void GenerateFlatBottoms(const Triangle& tri, vTris& newVTris) noexcept
    {
        Triangle topTri =
        {
            Triangle::FbTop(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::FbTop(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3)
            ),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::FbTop(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3)
            ),
        };

        Triangle bottomLeftTri =
        {
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::FbTop(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3)
            ),
            Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3)
            ),
        };

        Triangle bottomRightTri =
        {
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::FbTop(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3)
            ),
            Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3)
            ),
        };

        newVTris.push_back(topTri);
        newVTris.push_back(bottomLeftTri);
        newVTris.push_back(bottomRightTri);
    }

    void GenerateFlatTops(const Triangle& tri, vTris& newVTris) noexcept
    {
        
        Triangle topLeftTri =
        {
            Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::FtBottom(tri.p1, tri.p2,tri.p3)
            ),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2,tri.p3)
            ),
        };

        Triangle topRightTri =
        {
            Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::FtBottom(tri.p1, tri.p2,tri.p3)
            ),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2,tri.p3)
            ),
        };

        Triangle bottomTri =
        {
            Triangle::FtBottom(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::Right(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::FtBottom(tri.p1, tri.p2,tri.p3)
            ),
            Triangle::Mid
            (
                Triangle::Left(tri.p1, tri.p2, tri.p3), Triangle::FtBottom(tri.p1, tri.p2,tri.p3)
            ),
        };

        newVTris.push_back(topLeftTri);
        newVTris.push_back(topRightTri);
        newVTris.push_back(bottomTri);
    }

public:
    int GetCurrentIteration() const noexcept
    {
        return (int)vvTris.size() - 1;
    }

    const std::vector<vTris>& GetConstvvTris() const noexcept
    {
        return vvTris;
    }

    std::vector<vTris>& GetvvTris() noexcept
    {
        return vvTris;
    }

    void DoIteration() noexcept
    {
        //retrieve the last vector of triangles
        vTris vtris = vvTris.back(); 

        //holds the triangles generated in this 
        //iteration
        vTris newVTris{};

        //iterate through all the triangles in that vector 
        //and create new vector of inner triangles. Then
        //add that vector to vvTris.
        for (auto& tri : vtris)
        {
            //Each triangle generates four unqiue inner triangle
            GenerateMiddleTriangle(tri, newVTris);
            if (tri.flatTop)
            {
                GenerateFlatTops(tri, newVTris);
            }
            else
            {
                GenerateFlatBottoms(tri, newVTris);
            }
        }

        //Add the vector that contains the triangles form this
        //iteration to vvTris.
        vvTris.push_back(newVTris);
    }
    
    void UndoIteration() noexcept
    {
        //Dont want to be able to remove the first
        //triangle
        if (vvTris.size() > 1)
        {
            vvTris.pop_back();
        }
    }

    void Run(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
    {
        Input::OnDPress(pge, [this]() { this->DoIteration(); });
        Input::OnAPress(pge, [this]() { this->UndoIteration(); });
    }

    void Render(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
    {
        Gfx::Clear(pge);


        //Draw only the last iteration of the triangles + all
        //the flat tops
        for (auto& tri : vvTris.back())
        {
            Gfx::RenderTriangle(pge,
                World::WorldToScreen(tri.p1),
                World::WorldToScreen(tri.p2),
                World::WorldToScreen(tri.p3)
            );
        }

        for (auto& vtris : vvTris)
            for (auto& tri : vtris)
            {
                if (tri.flatTop)
                {
                    Gfx::RenderTriangle(pge,
                        World::WorldToScreen(tri.p1),
                        World::WorldToScreen(tri.p2),
                        World::WorldToScreen(tri.p3)
                    );
                }
            }

        Gfx::RenderNIterations(pge, (const int)GetCurrentIteration());
    }
};
```

graphics.h

```
#pragma once
#include "pixelGameEngine.h"

class Gfx
{
public:
    Gfx() = default;
    Gfx(const Gfx&) = delete;
    Gfx& operator=(const Gfx&) = delete;

public:
    static void Clear(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
    {
        pge->Clear(olc::BLACK);
    }

    static void RenderTriangle(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge, const olc::vf2d& p1, const olc::vf2d& p2, 
        const olc::vf2d& p3, olc::Pixel c = olc::WHITE) noexcept
    {
        auto testInScreen = [pge](const olc::vf2d& point)
        {
            return (
                point.x > 0 && point.x < pge->ScreenWidth() ||
                point.y > 0 && point.y < pge->ScreenHeight()
                );
        };

        if (testInScreen(p1) || testInScreen(p2) || testInScreen(p3))
        {
            pge->DrawTriangle(p1, p2, p3, c);
        }
    }

    static void RenderNIterations(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge, const int nIterations) noexcept
    {
        pge->DrawString({ 10, 10 }, "Iterations: " + std::to_string(nIterations));
    }
};
```

input.h

```
#pragma once
#include "pixelGameEngine.h"
#include <functional>

class Input
{
public:
    Input() = default;
    Input(const Input&) = delete;
    Input& operator=(const Input&) = delete;

public:
    static void OnDPress(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge, std::function<void()> DoIteration) noexcept
    {
        if (pge->GetKey(olc::D).bPressed)
        {
            DoIteration();
        }
    }

    static void OnAPress(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge, std::function<void()> UndoIteration) noexcept
    {
        if (pge->GetKey(olc::A).bPressed)
        {
            UndoIteration();
        }
    }
};

class WorldInput
{

public:
    WorldInput() = default;
    WorldInput(const WorldInput&) = delete;
    WorldInput& operator=(const WorldInput&) = delete;

private:
    static olc::vf2d startMousePan;

public:
    static void Drag(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge, olc::vf2d& offset, const float scale)
    {
        olc::vf2d mousePos = pge->GetMousePos();
        if (pge->GetMouse(0).bPressed)
        {
            startMousePan = mousePos;
        }
        if (pge->GetMouse(0).bHeld)
        {
            offset -= (mousePos - startMousePan) / scale;
            startMousePan = mousePos;
        }
    }

    static void Zoom(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge, float& scale)
    {   

        if (pge->GetKey(olc::W).bHeld)
        {
            scale *= 1.01f;
        }
        if (pge->GetKey(olc::S).bHeld)
        {
            scale *= 0.99f;
        }

        olc::vf2d afterZoom;
    }
};

olc::vf2d WorldInput::startMousePan{};
```

world.h

```
#pragma once
#include "pixelGameEngine.h"
#include "input.h"

class World
{
public:
    World() = default;
    World(const World&) = delete;
    World& operator=(const World&) = delete;

private:
    static olc::vf2d offset;
    static float scale;
    static WorldInput input;

public:
    static void SetOffset(const olc::vf2d& inoffset) noexcept
    {
        offset = inoffset;
    }

    static const olc::vf2d& GetOffset()  noexcept
    {
        return offset;
    }

    static void SetScale(const float inscale) noexcept
    {
        scale = inscale;
    }

    static const float& GetScale()  noexcept
    {
        return scale;
    }

public:
    static olc::vf2d ScreenToWorld(const olc::vf2d& v) noexcept
    {
        return (v / scale) + offset;
    }

    static olc::vf2d WorldToScreen(const olc::vf2d& v) noexcept
    {
        return (v - offset) * scale;
    }

    static void DragToChangeOffset(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
    {
        input.Drag(pge, offset, scale);
    }

    static void WSToChangeScale(olc::PixelGameEngine* pge) noexcept
    {
        olc::vf2d mousePos = pge->GetMousePos();
        olc::vf2d mouseBeforeZoom = ScreenToWorld(mousePos);

        input.Zoom(pge, scale);

        olc::vf2d mouseAfterZoom = ScreenToWorld(mousePos);

        offset += mouseBeforeZoom - mouseAfterZoom;
    }
};

WorldInput World::input{};
olc::vf2d World::offset = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
float World::scale = 1.0f;
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would provide a ZIP file of your source code.

Comment: @paladin [github](https://github.com/HippozHipos/triInsideTri)

Comment: `pixelGameEngine.h` is missing in git - I see, you've an external header -> https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/blob/master/olcPixelGameEngine.h

Comment: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/master/olcPixelGameEngine.h` - next time please include all needed files

Comment: Another missing header: _pixelGameEngine.h:3146:11: fatal error: GL/gl.h: file or directory cannot be found_ `#include <GL/gl.h>` - you should check your dependencies and add them all to your post

Comment: @paladin pixelGameEngine uses openGl for rendering. I am using visual studio so it sorted all of that out for me.

Comment: Is it that what you'll say to your customer? _"To play this game you've to fix all needed dependencies on your own. Have fun!"_ ;-)

Comment: @paladin But... but you are not a customer :). I am also not a professional, just doing this for fun So I didn't know people expect all the files to be in the github repo. Will keep that in mind next time, thank you

Comment: Well known standard libraries can be expected to be installed, but device dependent libraries cannot be expected to be installed and should be provided or linked at runtime.

Comment: Looks pretty good.  The use of C++ is much better than most of what gets posted here, so I don't have a list of things spotted on a quick reading.